# Bash script wrapper for tar command takes a very long time to execute

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm attempting to extract specific files of interest from a tar file (~50Gb). When I manually extract the file from the command line it takes a very short amount of time (1-2s). When I attempt to process it via a bash script to automate the specific files to extract, the script hangs at the tar extraction. I know it hangs here as I can kill the tar process and the script continues. The file gets extracted as I can "view" the file and contents while the script is still waiting for the tar process to return.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
for line in $contents
do
    if [ -f $line ]; then
            /bin/tar xf $tarfile -C $tmp $line
    fi
done
```

I attempted to create a subshell for just the tar extraction but then I had 100s of hanging tar processes. Any thoughts as to why this is the case?

Thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you extract all the files at once, instead of using a loop? Your way has to search the tar file from the beginning for each file.

Comment: I'd rather not extract a compressed 50Gb file... my issue is why would the command line version be so quick yet a bash script version take so long?

Comment: I mean `/bin/tar xf $tarfile -C $tmp $contents` to just extract those files.

Comment: There's also a bit of logic thats not included in this snippet and why im doing the if file exists statement... I'd like to know if this file exists or not and then proceed... I still feel like something is incorrect with either my syntax or something since the CLI version is so fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can supply multiple filename arguments to `tar` when extracting, so do:

```
/bin/tar xf $tarfile -C $tmp $contents
```

Your way has to search through the tarfile for each file being extracted. If it takes 1-2 seconds to extract a file, and you want to extract 50 files, that will take 50-100 seconds.

By supplying all the filenames at once, it scans through the tarfile just once, and extracts each file as it's encountered.

Comment: I was unaware of this option. I can rework my logic and just do one extraction as you mentioned.  thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo $contents | xargs find $start_directory -type f -name | xargs tar xvf $tarfile -C $tmp
```

Which (at least I think) adds your criterion for only extracting a file if it already exists and is a regular file.